# HasAndBelongsToMany returns unnecessary data

Tags: cakephp

When I fetch records using hasAndBelongsToMany it sends me the following output:

```
[Location] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [uuid] => 5a8e4d7f-e1d0-11e4-9567-c03fd5623744
        [name] => chandigarh
        [address_line1] => dummy
        [address_line2] => dummy
        [latitude] => 30.737780
        [longitude] => 76.784439
        [timezone] => UTC
        [is_deleted] => 0
        [created] => 2015-04-13 16:59:31
        [modified] => 2015-04-13
        [entry_ts] => 2015-04-13 16:59:31
    )

[Department] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [dept_name] => Heater
                [LocationDepartment] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [location_id] => 1
                        [department_id] => 1
                        [is_deleted] => 0
                        [created] => 2015-04-13 17:00:50
                        [modified] => 2015-04-13 17:00:50
                        [entry_ts] => 2015-04-13 17:00:50
                    )

            )
    )
```

But I don't need the `LocationDepartment` array. Can any one help me?

Comment: What does your actual find look like? Also, what version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If your using a quick find you can do this before you do it

```
$this->Location->recursive = 1;
$this->Location->findById($id);
```

If your using a full find you can add in recursive as part of the passed parameters

```
$this->Location->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id), 'recursive' => 1));
```

Posting your sample code will help solve something this simple

---

You can also include the 'containable' behavior on the Model which will let you specify exactly what models/data to retrieve back.

```
class Location extends AppModel {

  var $actsAs = array('Containable');

  function GetRecord($id) {
    return $this->find('first', array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $id,
      ),
      'contain' => array('Department'),
    );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual Location Model as this should be working (unrelated... I'm a girl lol)